# Potential leak of an object stored into 'string'

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

I am trying to Run the code but its reporting the memory leaks when using static analyzer.
on this line as Potential leak of an object stored into 'string'

```
return (__bridge NSString *)string;
```

here is the entire Method :

```
+(NSString *)GUID
{
CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
CFRelease(theUUID);
return (__bridge NSString *)string;
}
```

let me know if someone else need more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
+(NSString *)GUID
{
    CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
    CFRelease(theUUID);
    NSString *str = (__bridge NSString *)string;
    CFRelease(string);
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Your bridged cast does not transfer the ownership, thus the retain count is increased. Use __bridge_transfer instead.

Comment: Thank you. works for me +1 for you

Answer (score 3):

For iOS 6 and later use:

```
NSString *guid = [[NSUUID new] UUIDString];
NSLog(@"guid '%@'", guid);
```

NSLog output:

> guid 'C2635D23-557B-42C9-BE90-6E6001CC09F1'